# Save exact storage size of file(image,audio,video) from Angularjs to WepApi

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried to upload 2mb file but $scope.selectedFile.base64 length is more than 2mb but i want to save same file size

> Html

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="files" ng-model="selectedFile" base-sixty-four-input> 
<button  ng-click="vm.saveFile()"> Upload </button>
```

> Js

```
$scope.saveFile = function(){
 var data = {
                    fileType: $scope.selectedFile.filetype,
                    fileName: $scope.selectedFile.filename,
                    fileBase64 : $scope.selectedFile.base64,
                };
}

myService.uploaddDocument(data).then(function (response) {
}
```

I tried another way in this method, both (uploadFile.size and event.target.result.split(',')[1].length ) size are different

> Html

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="files" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged(event)">
```

> Js

```
$scope.fileChanged = function (files) {
 var uploadFile = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[0];
 console.log(uploadFile.size);
   var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.result.split(',')[1].length);
    }
}
```

So, Please tell me a solution for save same file size

Answer (score 0):

When (any) base64 string converts into byteArray in c# then the size of byteArray is equal to original file size.

> C# :

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

We can Calculate the actual size of file from base64 ( like base64 length * 0.75 = actual file size)